# Pulled revisions not being marked as public phase

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

I'm not sure if this is a problem with Mercurial or [TortoiseHG](http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/) (both version 3.6.1) but I've got an issue where revisions pulled from our [RhodeCode](https://rhodecode.com/) server have recently started being given "draft" phase on one particular development machine.

My own machine is pulling revisions and marking them correctly as "public", but my colleague always get "draft".  We are unaware of any recent changes to his configuration, and we've compared `mercurial.ini` and the `hgrc` files between our machines.

I'm still fairly clueless when it comes to Mercurial (despite having used it for the last 4 years), so I'm struggling to understand exactly what's happening.

Is there any particular setting (either in Mecurial or TortoiseHG) that would mean a revision pulled by me results in a local "public" phase, but when pulled by my colleague results in local "draft" phase?

Comment: This is normally something that happens on the server; if a repository is marked as [non-publishing](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Phases#Publishing_Repository), then pushed commits will remain in the draft phase. I don't know enough about RhodeCode, but apparently there [may have been a recent issue](https://rhodecode.tenderapp.com/help/discussions/problems/9038-pushed-commits-remain-in-draft-phase-when-interacting-with-rhodecode-310) with repositories be made non-publishing by default. Note that this is normally not harmful behavior. Why it's different for the two of you, I do not know.

Comment: Thanks @Reimer - I will continue to investigate.  As you say, it's not that harmful, but I believe it still could potentially cause problems if we're not careful

Comment: Just to note: 1) I see "draft" phase for changesets, pulled from Git-repo in my THG 2) RhodeCode support (except Mercurial) also Git+SVN repos

Answer (score 1):

There is a setting to check:

> Sometimes it may be desirable to push and pull changesets in the draft phase to share unfinished work. This can be done by setting a repository to disable publishing in its configuration file:
>
> [phases]
>   publish = False

Ref: https://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#phases

Answer (score 0):

This must be related to RhodeCode Phases control, Please check with your super admin for versions < 3.7 if they didn't un-set "set repositories as publishing" globally, if it's 3.7+ each repository has it's own Phases control under settings -> vcs.